# BizTalk Inbound receive port map is not working

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have created a map that comprised of Custom XSL and I need to use this map to convert the incoming message to desired format.
I am using all Pass through pipelines at a moment, for some reasons map is not yielding any results and producing the same as I supplied as input.

I have two file location as Input and Output, with two ports, send and receive.
Map is applied in receive port and its being subscribed by Send port via filter.

Could anyone help me with this as what could be the reason as there is no error anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Maps are resolved based on the .Net type of the Message which must be applied by a Pipeline Component.

In your case, you must use the XmlDisassembler in the Pipeline either through the default XmlReceive or a custom Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

As BizTalk doesnt support maps with Pass through pipeline hence its not working.